# Assistence with C# LDAP query

Tags: c#, ldap

I am receiving an LDAP malformed query notice when attempting to query our DC via C#...

I am trying to get a list of disabled Windows accounts.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc-7f-01.uidc.ccb");
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803: = 2 )");
```

Comment: Clarity: Actually the error says "invalid Filter" not "Malformed query"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to wrap your criteria in an `and`. Your filter string should be:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

You can read more about the filter syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax).

Comment: Hey itsme, I had tried the ampersand before and received the same message. This issue was that I need a second parenthesis at the end. I no longer receive the error but the thing returns nothing. Giving you credit for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick...
 mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";